# What is difference .sh file to change executable (chmod +x) and not?

Tags: shell, sh, executable, chmod

I notice when make a .sh file, usually, then we edit file's executable flag

```
$ chmod +x <sth>.sh
```

But without that executable flag, the .sh file can be executable.

```
$ sh ./<sth>.sh
```

why we need chmod?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Executable files define commands, and command names in UNIX should not have extensions. You run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, so it should likewise be `sth`, not `sth.sh`.

Comment: ...anyhow, `sh sth.sh` **doesn't** execute the script; it executes `sh`, which **reads** the script, but does not execute it in any way the operating system cares about (no `execv`-series call); hence the lack of need for execute permissions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I understand that.. but , is right what I understand that chmod and execution have wide functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "wide functionality" means in this context. If you mean that it's the more flexible approach, that would be accurate -- `sh foo` only is sure to work if `foo` is a script written to be compatible with the POSIX sh baseline specification, whereas `./foo` will work for a bash script, a ksh script, or even a Python or Perl script by honoring their shebang lines to select the interpreters those scripts are written for.

Comment: @charles Yeah, that's what i mean, really thanks! 
that's reason why i question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `chmod` and turning on execute permissions, you can just run the file using

```
<sth>.sh
```

Without executable permissions, if you have read permissions you can still run scripts but you must use an interpreter, such as `sh` or `bash`

When you do

```
 sh <sth>.sh
```

What this means is run the `sh` command, which **reads** the .sh file, and then interprets it, therefore you don't need execute permissions.

Comment: The `sh` command only applies if it's a POSIX script. For a bash script, `bash`; for a ksh script `ksh`, etc. Otherwise you'll get bugs if the interpreter providing `sh` doesn't provide features the script needs.

Comment: (and even if `/bin/sh` is provided by `bash`, it runs in a compatibility mode with numerous non-POSIX features turned off when run that way).

Comment: @bkmoney thanks!, I little understand... unix system is too complicate for me

Answer (score 1):

when you don't give the executable permission to the file , you have to mention with which binary you want to run your file .

for example you have to run file like

sh example.sh

but when you give the file executable permission you are allowed to run the file as ./example.sh

Comment: thanks, Have a nice day!